# Compile Console App to MSIL code

Tags: c#, .net, cil

I use Visual Studio 2012 and I code there simple console app. Does anyone know how get MSIL code from my C# code?
I would like to see it after compilation without ILDASM, it's possible to automaticate this process

Comment: Um. That's what .NET languages compile to. The compilation to native happens in the Jitter when a program is first run (assuming nGen is not used).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your output `exe` file will contain MSIL code. You can inspect it with [ildasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

I think it will be useful for you to read about [Compiling to MSIL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5tkafs1%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) on msdn.